# Reload UITableView inside UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've a main class called `ViewController` which is holding the `UIScrollView` and inside this `ViewController` I'm defining the three other controllers that is holding UITableViews as following :

```
let viewController1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1
let viewController2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2
let viewController3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! ViewController3
```

And then adding them to the scrollview.

I've implemented `UIScrollViewDelegate` so after finishing from scrolling it refresh my `UITableView` in that `ViewController`.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.frame.width

}
```

I got the page number, but how do i reload for example if i am in `ViewController2` which has `UITableView`?

Comment: Use an outlet reference and one of the `UITableView` reload methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but maybe [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) would be better suited for this purpose?

Comment: You should store the table view controller references in properties rather than local variables.

Comment: @SteveWilford , I've changed to UIScrollView to stop bouncing so its not a good idea !

Comment: I can't outlet UITableView which doesn't belong to my ViewController ! @A-Live

Comment: @AaoIi You can always outlet anything at storyboard, of course the way to access it will depend on how you use storyboard, in fact you'll normally end up frequently referencing other objects outlets rather than `self`'s outlets because packing all views logic into separate controllers isn't something done often.

Comment: @AaoIi You already have such references at `let viewController1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1 ...`

Comment: @A-Live, i tried to say `viewController1.mytableview.reloadData()` when the page is 0 and 1 and 2 , but it never refreshed anything !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an array of view controllers in your `ViewController`:

```
var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
```

Then set them up and add them to this array:

```
viewControllers.append(storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1)
viewControllers.append(storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2)
viewControllers.append(storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! ViewController3)
```

Then you can reference them in your scroll view delegate method:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let page = Int(floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.frame.width))
    if page < viewControllers.count {
        let viewController = viewControllers[page]
        // do whatever with viewController
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives an error `Cannot subscript a value of type [(UIViewController)] with an index of type (Float)` also how can i reload my UITableView from that controller. what is the proper way to define the controller and reload its UITableView ! ?

Comment: cast it as int! Use Float to Int conversion

Comment: Yes, the Float was supposed to be Int, updated answer.

Comment: @AaoIi you would need each view controller to conform to a protocol that exposed a `UITableView` property, or if possible make them all a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Then you could update the array definition with this new type.

Comment: it gives another error `Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type `

Comment: Updated answer again.